# Make custom logging for Class in log4j in Java

Tags: java, slf4j

I would like to log BigDecimal via toPlainString in SLF4J, how could I do that?

Example:

```
LOG.info("Value is {}", (BigDecimal)a) // Use a.toPlainString, not a.toString here.
```

Comment: Why are you not just using `a.toPlainString()`?

Comment: Because I don't want to but `a.toPlainString()` all 1000 and 1 places =(